# How to remove value has been exist in list table tr?

Tags: javascript

I have a sample code:

```
<table id="modem_list">
   <tr class="input_1" name="modem">
      <td>iPad 1<input type="hidden" value="1" class="output_1"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="input_2" name="modem">
      <td>iPad 2<input type="hidden" value="2" class="output_2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="input_1" name="modem">
      <td>iPad 1<input type="hidden" value="1" class="output_1"></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" class="submit" onclick="update()" value="submit" />
```

and javascript

```
function update() {
  var table = document.getElementById("modem_list");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for(var i=0; i<rowCount-1; i++) {
    for(var j=i+1; j<rowCount; j++) {
        if(table.rows[i] == table.rows[j]) {
            rowCount--;
            for(var k=j; k<rowCount; k++) {
                table.rows[k] = table.rows[k+1];
                table.deleteRow(k);
                k--;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

How to fix result is:

```
<table id="modem_list">
       <tr class="input_1" name="modem">
          <td>iPad 1<input type="hidden" value="1" class="output_1"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="input_2" name="modem">
          <td>iPad 2<input type="hidden" value="2" class="output_2"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: `if(row.className == row.className)` this deletes every row!

Comment: That's a very odd looking loop...

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do ?

Comment: @JeromeC.: From my understanding he wants to delete every row that has a class that was already assigned to a different row.

Comment: if (true) table.deleteRow(i);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove the repeated `tr` elements based on their classes, you can try this:

```
function update() {
    //caches a reference to which table we're working with
    var table = document.getElementById("modem_list");
    //gets all its rows
    var trs = table.rows;

    //iterates through all rows
    for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
        //stores possible dupes in an array
        var dupes = table.getElementsByClassName(trs[i].className);
        //if there are any dupes.. (more than 1 element with same class)
        if (dupes.length > 1)
            //removes all repeated elements except the first (index 0)
            for (var j=1; j<dupes.length; j++)
                dupes[j].parentNode.removeChild(dupes[j]);
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5bGUn/)**